# Unsure where to call release on an Object. Help?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a class that handles all the Network Access on the iPhone. And I use it in the following way:

```
-(void) randomFunction:
{
    // Assign params etc. <br />
    TTNetworkAccessLib *nLib = [[TTNetworkAccessLib alloc] initWithParams:..];
    [nLib createAndStartRequest];
    // Can't release here since the request is async and is still running.
}

-(void) requestSucceded:(NSData *) data
{
    // Can pass a reference to the request object and release here, but doesn't seem right?
}

-(void) requestFailed:(int) responseCode
{
    // Can pass a reference to the request object and release here, but doesn't seem right?
}
```

Comment: Do you call randomFunction: multiple times on the same instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I create an object to do something asynchronously, I usually have it retain itself when starting the procedure and release itself after finishing and completing any callbacks. This way, the code creating it can release it if it doesn't need it later, and I know it will not be deallocated until the process has completed.

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to do this, but I wasn't sure if this was how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

With a delegate like that I would recommend to use the autorelease
TNetworkAccessLib *nLib = [[[TTNetworkAccessLib alloc] initWithParams:..] autorelease];

Comment: Barring the TTNetworkAccessLib instance being retained by some other object, simply autoreleasing the instance will likely still cause it to be released before the async request finishes running.